# nonblocking thread with proper handling of child processess on windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, process

i have the main thread try to `CreateProcess()` but the main thread need to be non-blocking i am kind of lost on how to do this on windows on linux i am kinda know my way around but on windows

```
int main () {
    while (1) {

     // do some stuff 
     CreateProcess();    

     // i want a way to handle these processes exit codes and away of signaling when 
     the process has returned, i am thinking of using
     WaitForSingleObject() with 0 timeout but i dont know how to go about it 
     any help will be appreciated, thank you.


    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'proper handling of child processes'?

Comment: i don't want to create zombies neither i want to block the main thread and i want to signal when the process has finished.

Comment: Windows doesn't have zombies.  Just make sure you close the process and thread handles when you're finished with them and everything will be fine.  In this case, you would close the thread handle straight away and the process handle once you've detected that the process has exited.  It is easy to use WaitForSingleObject with a zero timeout to test whether the process has exited, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx